# Как извлекать из текстового файла первое число? Java

Tags: java, scanner

Имеется текстовый файл, в котором хранятся данные о сессиях:

```
1542384078773 668873060 236.215.100.166
1542384079774 161963738 194.42.176.2
1542384080774 378627692 37.138.100.42
1542384081774 335983167 254.241.160.5
1542384082774 798168250 68.167.208.123
```

И так далее, здесь в каждой строке первое число - это время начала сессии в миллисекундном формате (с начала 1970 года), второе число - это случайным образом сгенерированный 9-разрядный ID сессии, третье - это айпишник.

Стоит задача перезаписать этот файл, убрав из него данные о сессиях старше трех дней, например.

Каким образом можно выделять первое число в каждой строке, чтобы определять, удалять нам строку с этой сессией (она старше трех дней) или нет?

```
public void createNewListOfSessions(int ageInDays) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine().split(" ").get(0)) > (date.getTime() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
            SessionData session = new SessionData();
            session.setSessionStartTime(Long.parseLong(scanner.next()));
            session.setSessionID(scanner.next());
            session.setSessionIP(scanner.next());
            sessionsCounter++;
            scannedSessions.add(session);
        }
    }       
}
```

Здесь я попытался выделять первое число каждой строки через `scanner.nextLine().split(" ").get(0)`, но это неверно. Как правильно выделить это число?

В итоге получен такой на 100% работающий метод:

```
public void createNewListOfSessions(int ageInDays) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String[] current = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for (String subCurrent : current) {
            if ("".equals(subCurrent)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        Long sessionStartTime = Long.parseLong(current[0].trim());
        if (sessionStartTime > (date.getTime() - ageInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
            SessionData session = new SessionData();
            session.setSessionStartTime(sessionStartTime);
            session.setSessionID(current[1]);
            session.setSessionIP(current[2]);
            sessionsCounter++;
            scannedSessions.add(session);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Почему неверно?

Comment: Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type String[] - говорит Эклипс и подчеркивает красным.

Comment: можете ещё с помощью регулярных выражений...

Answer (score 3):

> Здесь я попытался выделять первое число каждой строки через
>   scanner.nextLine().split(" ").get(0), но это неверно. Как правильно
>   выделить это число?

Почему неверно? Всё верно, только у вас получается так, что вы считываете всю строку, ради одного числа и ваш курсор/указатель в файле уже прочитал эту строку, соответственно последующий вызов `scanner.next()` уже обращается к следующей строке. А, ну да, и у массивов нет метода `get`, к элементам обращаются с помощью оператора `[]`.

```
if (Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine().split(" ").get(0)) > (date.getTime() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
```

Вот тут внутри if вы считываете следующую строку до конца (`scanner.nextLine()`):

```
1542384078773 668873060 236.215.100.166
```

И дальше по коду, **вы ожидаете** видимо **что** у вас **считаются** по новой **значения** **первой строки**, **но это не так**, у вас будет читаться уже вторая строка.

```
session.setSessionStartTime(Long.parseLong(scanner.next())); //читается 1542384079774
session.setSessionID(scanner.next()); //читается 161963738
session.setSessionIP(scanner.next()); //читается 194.42.176.2
```

Чтобы этого не происходило, удобнее один раз считать строку и сохранить, разбить её с помощью `split` на части, и работать уже с ними, например:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String[] current = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    if (Long.parseLong(current[0]) > (date.getTime() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
        SessionData session = new SessionData();
        session.setSessionStartTime(Long.parseLong(current[0]));
        session.setSessionID(current[1]);
        session.setSessionIP(current[2]);
        sessionsCounter++;
        scannedSessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

Ещё, старайтесь избавляться в коде от одинаковых повторяющихся действий

```
Long.parseLong(current[0])
```

вы парсите число из одной и той же строки два раза подряд, в `if` и тут же в `set` методе. Зачем? Достаточно один раз это сделать:

```
String[] current = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
String sessionStartTime = Long.parseLong(current[0]);
if (sessiongStartTime > ...) {
    ...
    session.setSessionStartTime(sessionStartTime);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но при исполнении где-то получается пустая строка или находится пробел после действия 'split' и получается ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631) Подсмотрено здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597841/long-parselong-gives-java-lang-numberformatexception

Comment: Это надо смотреть ваш формат данных. Если он такой, как пример в вопросе, без лишних пробелов и whitespace, то всё должно быть хорошо. Видимо у вас есть отклонения от этого формата. Посколько вы где-то получаете пустуюу строку, после split, вероятно, что где-то есть лишние пробелы. Можно попробовать вызывать split с регуляркой вида `split("\\s+")` или фильтровать полученный после `split` массив на пустые строки.

Comment: Использование .split("\\s+") не помогло. Даже добавление .trim() не помогло - Long sessionStartTime = Long.parseLong(current[0].trim()). Видимо, действительно надо фильтровать полученный массив на пустые строки...

Comment: Ну ещё можете делать как вы делали до этого, читать токены методом `next`, но первое значение сохраняйте

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, где прячется эта пустая строка. Вернулся к задаче на свежую голову через несколько дней - пытался профильтровать пустые строки на основе примера из вышеприведенной ссылки с помощью foreach: for (String subCurrent : current) {
    if ("".equals(subCurrent))
     continue;.....} - не получается отловить пустой элемент, который не может быть затем в тип Long преобразоваться... Казалось бы - такая тривиальная задача, но из-за этого мелкого бага не могу её уже вторую неделю закончить.

Comment: Не может быть причиной проблемы использование символа переноса строки "\n" после каждого айпишника при записи файла? Когда этот файл со списком сессий формируется, он записывается таким образом:    file.write(sessions.get(i).getSessionStartTime() + " " + sessions.get(i).getSessionID() + " " + sessions.get(i).getSessionIP() + "\n");

Comment: символ переноса строки, если он там всего один должен съедаться методом `nextLine()`, это же для него и есть граница строки.

Comment: Я не знаю, что случилось, но сегодня вернулся к этой задаче в Эклипс - и все заработало... Ничего не изменял с 04 декабря... Единственное что - программа записывает каждую нужную строку по три раза подряд.

Comment: Все, победил проблему!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы правильно считать строку лучше использовать какой нибудь `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(".../foo.txt")));
String session = "";
if (reader.ready()) session  = reader.readLine();
reader.close();
```

Распарсить данный вариант проще всего сделав `substring`:

```
String timeStr = session.substring(0, session.indexOf(" "));
```

Класс Date сейчас считается устаревшим, как минимум и в нем не реализовано много полезных функций для работы с временем и датами. Лучше работать с новыми классами типа `LocalDateTime`. Например мы можем легко округлить интересующее нас время с точностью до дня.

```
    // получаем объект времени сессии 
    LocalDateTime sessionDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(timeStr))
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDateTime();
    // округляем до целого дня (если нужно) 
    sessionDate = sessionDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(sessionDate); // проверяем

    // получаем объект референсного времени, до которого надо все отфильтровать 
    LocalDateTime requestDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3); // дней назад
    requestDate = requestDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(requestDate); // проверяем

    // сравниваем эти два объекта и что то делаем, например перезаписываем строку в другой файл
    if (sessionDate.isAfter(requestDate)) {
        // do something
        System.out.println("+++++++ date is valid");
    }
```

Не забудьте указать `Locale`, и вы сможете проще и более гибко обращаться с объектами дата/время.